# explanation of this cosine solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was studying Physics and I stumbled upon this equation: $$U_0 \cos{x}(\cos{x} - 1) = \alpha U_0$$ So you should get the value of x to do some other stuff.
The equation doesn't seem to complex, however our professor just straight up came up with the solution. It is still not as easy to just not do any steps in between. He wrote the following solution:
$$\cos{x} = \frac{1}{2} (1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha})$$

Can someone explain how he calculated this.

Comment: You are essentially trying to solve $y$ for $y(y-1) = \alpha$. It's a quadratic polynomial in $y$.

Comment: Ofcourse. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(\cos x)(\cos x-1)=\alpha\iff \cos^2 x-\cos x-\alpha=0,
$$
which is a quadratic equation in $\cos x$. Now applying the quadratic formula gives
$$
\cos x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2},
$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: I would say $\iff$ instead of $\implies.$